# Pandas calculate minimum for pairs of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'col1': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', "A", "B"], 
        'col2': ["0", "2", "0", "1", "0", "0.5"]}  
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df 

   col1 col2
0   A   0
1   B   2
2   A   0
3   B   1
4   A   0
5   B   0.5
```

There are three pairs of rows (A,B). For each pair I calculate the absolute difference of the numbers in col2. My goal is to get the minimum absolute difference of the three pairs and the corresponding Index. In this case this is 0.5 respectively 4.

I already tried:

```
(df[df["col1"] == "A"]["col2"] - df[df["col1"] == "B"]["col2"]).abs().min()
```

But I got a problem with the index.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Hello. This is a bit unclear " In this case this is 0.5 respectively 4.". Could you explain? Do you expect the difference between values assigned to 'A' or 'B' regardless of their row? From your code I understand you want to calculate the minimum of the array comprised of the absolute difference between the two subsets A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one line of code:

```py
df.col2.diff().abs().shift(-1)[::2].agg(['idxmin', 'min']).values.tolist()
```

It returns a list with:

- the index of the row corresponding to the start of the sequence `A-B` with the minimum absolute difference;
- the value of the absolute difference.

Here the output:

```sh
[4.0, 0.5]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with

```
s = df.iloc[::-1].groupby(df.index//2).col2.diff().abs()
out = s.agg(['min','idxmin'])
Out[193]: 
min       0.5
idxmin    4.0
Name: col2, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
import numpy as np
df.loc[:,'col2'] = df.col2.astype(np.float)
df[(df.col2 == min(df[df.col2 > 0].col2)) ]
```

Correct?

Comment: It returned index 5, but the correct minimum difference

Answer (score 1):

To fix the indexing problem you asked about, use `.loc` with the comparison expression as the row indexer and `'col2'` for the column indexer. I've added `astype` to enable the math later.

```
>>> x = df.loc[df.col1=='A','col2'].astype(float)
>>> y = df.loc[df.col1=='B','col2'].astype(float)
>>> x
0    0.0
2    0.0
4    0.0
Name: col2, dtype: float64
>>> y
1    2.0
3    1.0
5    0.5
Name: col2, dtype: float64
```

To subtract the resultant DataFrames reindex the `'B'` DataFrame like the `'A'` DataFrame to ensure you can recover the original index of the `'A'` row.

```
>>> z = x - y.reindex_like(x,method='bfill')
>>> z
0   -2.0
2   -1.0
4   -0.5
Name: col2, dtype: float64
```

Extract what you are looking for.

```
>>> z.abs().agg(['min', 'idxmin'])
min       0.5
idxmin    4.0
Name: col2, dtype: float64
>>>
```

---

Unfortunately it is not a one-liner.